# QBXML for Bill Add request

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml, qbwc

I need some help in my current implementation of automating the Bills flow from our system to QB. I have done all necessary changes that will pass the Bills related information from our system to QB and expect to save it under Bill on QB . Below is sample qbxml i am requesting. But i am getting below error message from QB. Please guide me if any change needed in the xml request.

***Error message from QB:***

```
20200325.16:57:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.
20200325.16:57:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #2
20200325.16:57:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from pplication: size (bytes) = 711
20200325.16:57:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to uickBooks.
20200325.16:57:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending error message back to application:
HRESULT = 0x80040400
**Message: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.**
20200325.16:57:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -
```

**Request that failed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?><?qbxml versi......**
```

***QBXML request:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <BillAddRq requestID="9240">
            <BillAdd>
                <VendorRef>
                    <FullName>ALERNER</FullName>
                </VendorRef>
                <TxnDate>2020-03-25</TxnDate>
                <DueDate>2020-03-24</DueDate>
                <RefNumber>100</RefNumber>
                <TermsRef>
                    <FullName>Net 30 Days</FullName>
                </TermsRef>
                <Memo>via access</Memo>
                <Address>
                    <Adr1>1060 N Kings Hway Suite 220</Adr1>
                    <City>Cherry Hill</City>
                    <State>NJ</State>
                    <PostalCode>08034</PostalCode>
                    <Country></Country>
                </Address>
                <ItemLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <ListID>430001 - 1197741385</ListID>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>1 cubed mice</Desc>
                    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
                    <Cost>5</Cost>
                    <Amount>6</Amount>
                </ItemLineAdd>
            </BillAdd>
        </BillAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you see this:

`QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.`

It means your XML either isn't valid, or doesn't match the `XSD` Intuit has defined to validate against required fields / data types / etc.

The *very first thing you should do* when you run into this is use the `XML Validator` tool that is *included with the QuickBooks SDK*. Don't go use one online, *use the one included with the QuickBooks SDK* because it not only validates the XML structure itself, but validates data types, field lengths, element ordering, etc. against the `XSD`s.

In this case, your issue is that `Address` is not a valid element at all (you're probably looking for `VendorAddress`).

You can also refer to Intuit's documentation:

- OSR: https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html
- Docs: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/billadd

Edit: 
OSR link has been updated for some reason use the following link
https://static.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/common/newosr/index.html